# mysql advanced group query

Tags: mysql

I need some help figuring out a query

I have 3 tables

```
sources
id, name, rank

origin
id, source_id (FK to sources id), name

One source can have many origins

product
id, origin_id (FK to origin id), name, time_added

One origin can have many products
```

Now, what I want is to select the most recent products per source, ordered by rank descending

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you give some sample output records?

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately not. The above description is just a simplified version of the real tables and data. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do as you have requested, though without sample output it's hard to be 100% certain.  Inner query selects products linked to the source id ordered by the date added from newest to oldest, and in turn that's joined to sources and grouped.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM sources AS s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        origins.source_id,
        product.*
     FROM origin
     INNER JOIN product
     ON product.origin_id = origin.origin_id
     ORDER BY time_added DESC
) AS productsOrdered
ON productsOrdered.source_id = sources.source_id

ORDER BY s.rank DESC, productsOrdered.time_added DESC
```

This avoids having to do potentially expensive opreations as the inner select should be pretty fast and can be limited as required

Comment: Awesome man. The only thing missing is the GROUP BY s.id before the order

Comment: A follow up on the above answer. I have tried to put a second column to the order by, ie ORDER BY sources.rank DESC, time_added DESC, but it is not working. Does the subquery pose any restrictions to the ORDER BY clause?

Comment: ORDER BY s.rank, productsOrdered.time_added would work fine.  The subquery is effectively a table named productsOrdered for purposes of the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

A typical way of doing this is to

- Find the `MAX(time_added)` for each origin
- Get the product's `id` for each of these origins
- Join with the `sources` and `origin` tables to retrieve all columns

Note that this *fails* if there are origins with multiple records with the exact same `time_added`.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sources s
        INNER JOIN origin o ON o.source_id = s.id
        INNER JOIN product p ON p.origin_id = o.id
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  id
          FROM    product p
                  INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT  origin_id
                            , MAX(time_added) AS time_addded
                    FROM    product p
                    GROUP BY
                            origin_id
                  ) pmax ON pmax.origin_id = p.origin_id
                            AND pmax.time_added = p.time_added                            
        ) pmax ON pmax.id = p.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.id,count(o.id) as numOfProdFromOrig p.id, p.name, p.time_added, s.rank
FROM product as p NATURAL JOIN sources as s NATURAL JOIN origin as o
GROUP BY (numOfProdFromOrig)
ORDER BY s.rank DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.id,(select p.name from  origin o inner join product p
on p.origin_id = o.id where o.source_id = b.id order by time_added desc limit 1)a as product_name
from source b ;
```

Try this: